# I want to get a family of a settled person in uk visa

Tags: uk-visa

I’m 17 years old somali girl. I live in somalia I have done my igcses with the help of my aunt who lives in uk and now she wants me to go to uk to her so that I can live with her but we both don’t know if it is possible since I got a Somali passport 
If you guys have any idea of how this can work please tell me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you researched the visa conditions? https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa It’s not clear from your question which category you think you’d be eligible for.

Comment: Yes it said I can go with family of a settled person visa I’m too young for that one

Comment: You can: Apply as a partner or spouse, or 
Apply as a parent, or Apply as a child, or Apply as an adult coming to be cared for by a relative (because you need long-term care to do everyday personal and household tasks because of illness, disability or your age) or Apply on the basis of your private life. Which of these are you eligible to apply under?